# Linq to DataGridView, AutoGenerateColumns = False displays blank rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datagridview

My DGV has pre-formatted columns via the designer. With SQL, I could load the `SqlDataReader` result to a `DataTable` and simply loop through the columns to set the `DataPropertyName` property there.

I'm now migrating to LINQ; setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` with:

```
Dim result = From a In db.states
             Select a

DataGridView1.DataSource = result
```

...seems to only display a blank grid (while retaining the columns).  Help? I want formatting of the grid columns to be done at the designer as much as possible. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Setting the `DataPropertyName` one by one seems to work:

```
col1.DataPropertyName = "id"
col2.DataPropertyName = "name"
```

Is there a way to convert this to a routine, possibly with a loop, so I don't have to set everything manually?  Kinda like this (with a `DataTable`):

```
For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1 : List.Columns(i).DataPropertyName = dt.Columns(i).ColumnName : Next
```

Comment: `.ToList()` must work. Is columns `DataPropertyName` have same names as properties names in your states collection?

Comment: Hey Fabio, thanks, please see my edits! :)

Comment: If you created column in the designer - then you can set those in designer too. If you want dynamic then set `AutoGenerateColumns = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you still need to convert this into list like so:

```
Dim result = From a In db.states
             Select a

DataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList() 'converts to list
```

Comment: It didn't made a difference unfortunately. :(

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I'm pretty sure this works on me though.

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF?

Comment: Winforms.  My results return the right number of rows (from the database), although they are blank... I think this has something to do with the DataPropertyName property?

Comment: I think it's because you're using a wizard to preformat your datagrid. Have you tried directly loading the result in datasource without configuring your datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding BindingSource:

```
Dim result = From a In db.states
             Select a

Dim bs = New BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = result
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```